# What are the different types of databases?

Tags: terminology, reference-request, databases

Is there is a study or classification available on different types of databases? (Examples include structured, unstructured, semi structured relational, object oriented, folksonomies, etc.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One of the key differences between the different paradigms for data management is the underlying structure used to bind pieces of data together. IMHO, the difference between structured, unstructured, semi-structured is not precise enough : the point is that the underlying structure may be more or less flexible. This formal structure is used to define the semantics of the model and so it drives everything: the query language, the concrete (in memory, on disks) data-structures, the graphical representation etc.

In the standard [relational paradigm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Relational_model#The_model), the core concept is that of a tuple (in the set theoretic sense). XML variants are clearly [tree based](http://web.cs.wpi.edu/~mmani/toit/taxonomy/new/taxonomy.pdf), RDF related models are grounded on [labelled directed multi-graphs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Resource_Description_Framework#Overview): those three models are examplified in this [recent draft paper](http://arxiv.org/abs/1211.1565).
Nowadays, one talks about [stream data models](http://infolab.stanford.edu/stream/) grounded on infinite relations, [key-values stores](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NoSQL#Key.E2.80.93value_store) are grounded on functions/maps. I guess folksonomy may be multi-set oriented etc.

So "the study of different types of databases" may turn out to be "the study of formal data-structure useful for large data management".

Answer (score 3):

Wikipedia has a list of database models: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_model

Comment: They don't talk about NoSQL, though, and a few other models. Maybe the author of that article did not consider NoSQL as a database.